# How to add an event to elements which were created at run-time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, the *Add* button dynamically appends `<TR>`, which contains a *Remove* button, to a table. The following code `$('a.remove_performer').live()` gets the error of "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" and the event handler cannot be attached?

**Update:**
Changed the `live()` to `on()` and the error is gone. However, the event handler is still not attached.

http://jsfiddle.net/emg9yxwc/1/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="performerBody"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="performerList" name="performerList" class="valid">
                    <option value="1">performer1</option>
                    <option value="2">performer2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><a id="addNewPerformer" href="#" class="add_performer">Add</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Add new row
    $("#addNewPerformer").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $last = $("#performerBody tr:last");
        var index = 0;
        if ($last.length > 0) {
            index = $last.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
            index = parseInt(index) + 1;
        }
        var selected = $("#performerList").val();
        if ($('#performerBody input[value="' + selected + '"]').length === 0) {
            var name = "Performers[" + index + "].Id";
            var selectedText = $("#performerList :selected").text();
            $("#performerBody").append('<tr><td><span style="display:none"><input name="' + name + '" type="number" value="' + selected + '"></span>' + selectedText + '</td><td><a href="#" class="remove_performer">Remove</a></td></tr>');
        }
    });

    // Remove
    $('a.remove_performer').on("click", function (e) { // was live
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `.live()` is depriciated use `.on()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in **1.7** and removed in **1.9**

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

As per your code. Use

```
$("#performerBody").on('click', 'a.remove_performer', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```